# What are the possible relations?

Tags: functions, relations, binary

If there are two sets A and B. Set A has two elements so does Set B. How many different possible relations can we have from A to B. For example. Set A has (David, Max) and Set B has (x,y).

Would the possible relations simply be these four? Can we have 16 different possible relations? 
{David, x}
{David, y}
{Max, x}
{Max, y}

Comment: Yes, the answer is 16. A relation is just a subset of $A\times B$, and you should be able to get a formula for the number of such subsets along the lines of computing that 16.

Comment: Is the relation commutative? If so $a\cdot b = b\cdot a$, but in general $a\cdot b \ne b \cdot a$, so there are all permutations of these elements. Hence just these $4$

Comment: How can there be 16? If a relation is a subset of A x B then there can be only 4 correct?

Comment: The number of elements of $A \times B$ is $2*2=4$. When considering a subset of $A \times B$, each of the four elements of $A \times B$ may independently either be included in the subset or not, so in all there are $2*2*2*2=2^4=16$ possible subsets.

Answer (score 0):

These are the 16 possible relations:

1. null set
2. {David, x} {David, y} {Max, x} {Max, y}
3. {David, x} {David, y} {Max, x}
4. {David, y} {Max, x} {Max, y}
5. {David, x} {Max, x} {Max, y}
6. {David, y} {Max, y} {David, x}
7. {David, x} {David, y}
8. {David, x} {Max, x}
9. {Max, x} {Max, y}
10. {David, y} {Max, x}
11. David, y} {Max, y}
12. {David, x} {Max, y}
13. {David, x}
14. {Max, y}
15. {Max, x}
16. {David, y}